# how to populate/get values from existing controller into a form field using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

i have written a html file which adds users and it also has a edit and delete user button on clicking the add user button i am using bootstrap so there is a pop form menu which asks for details regarding user now i want to populate the same pop form menu when the user clicks the on edit button

i have written the following code but how do i populate the form value
This is for java script and

```
  $scope.editUser = function (user) {
            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'edit-form.html',
                controller: editModalInstance,
                scope: $scope,
                resolve: {
                    editForm: function () {
                        return $scope.editForm;
                    }
                }
            });
            modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
                user.firstname = selectedItem.firstname;
                user.lastname = selectedItem.lastname;
                user.pno = selectedItem.pno;
                user.emailid = selectedItem.emailid;
                $scope.selected = 'closed';
            });
        };


var editModalInstance = function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
    $scope.form = {};
    $scope.submitForm = function () {
        if ($scope.form.editForm.$valid) {
            $modalInstance.close($scope.form);
        }
    };
    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
};
```

Template Url:-

`

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="firstname" ng-model="form.firstname" ng-required="true" value="$scope.user.firstname">
        <div ng-show="form.editForm.firstname.$dirty && form.editForm.firstname.$invalid">
            <small>Invalid First Name</small>
        </div>
    </div>
```

`

so how do i use the value in the form field so that on clicking the edit button of the user i place the values in their respective form field

Comment: i didnt get you.did you mean upload whole code?

Comment: just add editModalInstance code..that would be enough

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/pu7RNiFqDdUdcXJxL9mZ

Comment: i have already edited for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the below code

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('myController', function ($scope, $uibModal) {
  'use strict';
   $scope.users = [
            {
                firstname: 'Bad',
                lastname: 'man',
                pno: 123456789,
                emailid: 'badman@123.com'
            }];
   $scope.removeUser = function (user) {
            var removedUser = $scope.users.indexOf(user);
            $scope.users.splice(removedUser, 1);
        };
   $scope.openModal = function () {
    $uibModal.open({
      templateUrl: 'modal.html',
      controller: function ($scope, $uibModalInstance) {
        $scope.ok = function () {
          $uibModalInstance.close();
        };

        $scope.cancel = function () {
          $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };
      }
    })
  };
   $scope.editUser = function (user) {
            var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                templateUrl: 'edit-form.html',
                controller: 'editModalInstance',
                scope: $scope,

                resolve: {
                    editForm: function () {
                        return user;
                    }
                }
            });
            modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
                user.firstname = selectedItem.firstname;
                user.lastname = selectedItem.lastname;
                user.pno = selectedItem.pno;
                user.emailid = selectedItem.emailid;
                $scope.selected = 'closed';
            });
        };


        $scope.showForm = function () {

            var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                templateUrl: 'form.html',
                controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
                scope: $scope,
                resolve: {
                    userForm: function () {
                        return $scope.userForm;
                    }
                }
            });

            modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
                $scope.selected = selectedItem;
                if (selectedItem === 'error') {
                    alert('There is already a user with the email id.Try with a new one.' +
                        '');
                }
            });
        };
});



app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance,userForm) {
    $scope.form = {};
    $scope.submitForm = function () {
        if ($scope.form.userForm.$valid) {
            var push_into = 1;
            for (var index = 0; index < $scope.users.length; index++) {
                if ($scope.users[index].emailid === $scope.form.emailid) {
                    push_into = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (push_into) {
                $scope.users.push({
                    firstname: $scope.form.firstname,
                    lastname: $scope.form.lastname,
                    pno: $scope.form.pno,
                    emailid: $scope.form.emailid,
                });
                $uibModalInstance.close('closed');

            }
            else {
                $uibModalInstance.close('error');

            }
        }
    };
    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
});
app.controller('editModalInstance', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance,editForm) {
     $scope.form = {};
     $scope.form=editForm;


    $scope.submitForm = function () {
        if ($scope.form.editForm.$valid) {
            $uibModalInstance.close($scope.form);
        }
    };
    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
});
```

Also check the plunkr for reference:

https://plnkr.co/edit/gt7FS4DNRjwLVyFOCZqx?p=preview

Comment: thanks and can u explain the resolve part in the code as i did not understand it from the start

Comment: Resolve is used when we want to pass data from parent controller to pop up controller.The data can be passed as dependency injection to the pop up controller

Answer (score 0):

I have used this feature in my project. You can do so just by defining the same variable in $scope when you get response for editing.

Let us follow me:
1. Suppose you have two input fields one for 'name' and one for 'lastname'.You asked the user to enter the details and user fills it.

```
    First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName">
    Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName">
```

As you are using ANGULAR you get the values from ng-model and submit the form and saved the details.

2. Now when you click edit button it's obvious that you have to match any id or key[for matching which user we want to edit].
3. you get all the details by matching the token[means name and lastname].
4. now you simply have to define the pre-bonded variables[i.e in ng-model]

   ```
   function edit(){
   //Any request to server and result of user in response
   $scope.firstname=response.firstname;
   $scope.lastname=response.lastname;[or whatever you are retrieving]
   }
   ```

5.now it will automatically fill the form with the details get from your response and you can easily edit whatever you want. Just look at demo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="hello" ng-controller="editUser">

First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
<br>
Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('hello', []);
app.controller('editUser', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "MY mane is";
    $scope.lastName = "Aryan";
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

```
Hope this helps you I can explain further if you need.
```